# What is the log-likelihood formulation for a combined normally distributed dataset?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, log-likelihood

Consider a sample (i.i.d) $C_{1},...,C_{n}$ that is normally distributed ~$N(µ,1)$ and a sample (i.i.d) $D_{1},...,D_{n}$ ~$N(\theta,1)$, we say $µ\neq\theta$.

Now I want to formulate a **log-likelhood function** for the **combined dataset**, X with $2n$ observations. Would it be valid to formulate it like:

$l=-\frac{n}{2}log\left(2\pi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(C_i-\mu\right)^2-\frac{n}{2}log\left(2\pi\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(D_i-\theta\right)^2$

Comment: If the two samples are independent then their joint likelihood is (proportional to) the product of their individual likelihoods and their joint log-likelihood is the sum of their individual log-likelihoods (up to an additive constant).  So with that assumption, what you have written looks reasonable (and you can drop the constant $-\frac{n}{2}\log\left(2\pi\right)$ terms  if you wish).

Comment: The samples indeed are independent. If I understand you correctly, I should calculate the log likelihood for the sample C and D seperatly and then sum their values? Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Yes, though I am saying you *can* rather than that you *should*.  My point is that it does not matter when you take the logarithm, before or after taking the product/sum across or within the two samples.  $\sum \log(a_i) + \sum \log(b_j) = \log(\prod a_i) + \log(\prod b_j) = \log(\prod a_i\prod b_j)$

Comment: I should re-study my mathematical properties again... I understand it now. Thanks for your help!